# How do I copy only the diff of the content from one file to another file?

Tags: python, file-io, text-files

I have two files, source file and dest file. I want to copy the content from this source file to the dest file, but **not the whole content**. **Only that part which is there in the source file and not in dest file.**

I tried to search and came across shutil module but I couldn't find any function that copies only the diff of content from one file to other.

How to do this in Python? Do we have any library function to accomplish this?

**Example:**

```
source.txt:     dest.txt
a               a
b               c
c               e
d               f
e
```

**After the desired operation, it should be:**

```
source.txt:     dest.txt
a               a
b               c
c               e
d               f
e               b
                d
```

Note that the order of lines doesn't matter.

Comment: Why Python ? `Git` server the purpose better !

Comment: Could you provide some input and output samples? Do you want to copy any difference and just the difference itself or do you want to copy whole lines that are different at some point, ...

Comment: but git, svn, or similar would actually merge the two files, and insrt the differences at the proper location. The questions example explicitly show that you want the differences AFTER the previous content.. Why you would prefer this, I don't know, but the normal tools wouldn't do it this way, as they are intended for texts where placement matter, like ... text, or code, or binary files

Answer (score 1):

If you can arrange your files to be lists of lines, we can accomplish this very easily.

```
if len(lineList1) > len(lineList2):
    src = lineList1
    dst = lineList2
else
    src = lineList2
    dst = lineList1
for x in range(len(src)):
    if src[x] != dst[x]
        dst[x] = scr[x]
```

This snippet, finds the longest list, iterates over both, and if the line isn't the same on the destination, it is copied. Although I'm unsure the benefits of this approach over copying the file; except for practice.

**EDIT**

I think I understand. Try this snippet:

```
output = dst + [x for x in src if x not in dst]
```

This iterates over every line and if its not in `dst` it's added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**Use difflib**

```html
import difflib
file1 = "PATH OF FILE 1"
file1 = open(file1, "r")
file2 = "PATH OF FILE 2"
file2 = open(file2, "r")
diff = difflib.ndiff(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines())
file1.close()
file2.close()
delta = ''.join(x[2:] for x in diff if x.startswith('- '))
fh = open("PATH OF FILE 2", "a")
fh.write(delta)
fh.close
fh = open("PATH OF FILE 2","r")
print fh.read()
fh.close()
```